# Select distinct rows based on two columns with additional columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table such as this

Blog

```
Id  ColumnId DateCreated Type
1     1      2018-01-01   1
1     1      2018-01-02   2
1     1      2018-02-01   3
```

I need to select all unique rows based on the combination of `Id` and `ColumnId`.  Then it needs to grab me the latest date and largest Type. I can't seem to figure this out.

I started of with just getting distinct values like this:

```
SELECT Id, ColumnId
FROM Blog
GROUP BY Id, ColumnId
```

Then I figured if I maybe joined it on itself I can pull out the rest, but I'm having no luck how to accomplish this

```
SELECT *
FROM ( SELECT Id, ColumnId
       FROM Blog
       GROUP BY Id, ColumnId) A
INNER JOIN Blog B ON A.Id = B.Id AND A.ColumnId = B.ColumnId
```

But that just gives me back all 3 rows.

In my live example the `Id` column is not `int`, but `uniqueidentifier`. For sake of simplicity I made it int in my example.

Expected Result Sample:

```
Id  ColumnId DateCreated Type
1     1      2018-02-01   3
```

Comment: then exshow the expected

Comment: seems you want the last  ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using `MAX`?

```
SELECT Id, ColumnId, MAX(DateCreated), MAX([Type])
FROM Blog
GROUP BY Id, ColumnId
```

Comment: I'm not sure why I didn't think of it. Now I feel rather foolish.

Answer (score 2):

Use `row_number()`:

```
select b.*
from (select b.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id, columnid order by date desc, type desc) as seqnum
      from blog b
     ) b
where seqnum = 1;
```

This grabs the largest type on the latest date, which is how I interpret "it needs to grab me the latest date and largest Type."

Answer (score 1):

seems you need  the last
you could use an inner join on the max date

```
select * from blog 
inner join  (
  select id, columnId, max(DateCreated) as max_date 
  from blog  
  group by id, columnId 

) t on t.id = blog.id, t.columnId = blog.columnId and t.max_date  = blog.DateCreated
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is not the best solution, but you could try to use a subselect in your query.
Something like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT Id, ColumnId, (SELECT MAX(Type) FROM blog) AS type
FROM Blog
```